# time unix_timestamp converter javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

does anyone have time to help me with a little problem? I did this function to check the license time but it doesn't really work, does anyone have any idea?
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/953617052202074132/954398145868083291/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/953617052202074132/954398654217723914/unknown.png

````
exilied_client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}time`)) {
        automex = message.author;
        if(message.guild == undefined) {
            message.reply("Comenzile le poti da doar pe server-ul de discord");
            return;
        };
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has(zedu_roldiscord)) {
            const argomento = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g)
            const comando = argomento.shift().toLowerCase();
            var i = 1;
            if(argomento[0])
            {
                if(message.member.roles.cache.has(zedu_roldiscord))
                {
                    var verificaretimp = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.fetch(argomento[1]))
                } else {
                    message.delete()
                    message.reply(automex.username + "  Ce gatu ma-tii vrei sa faci?")
                    return;
                }

            } else {
                var verificaretimp = automex
            }
            
            const Verificare = `SELECT license, used, total_time FROM licenses WHERE userid = '${verificaretimp.id}';`
            const autoreasd = querytxt => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    exilied_database.query(querytxt, (err, results, fields) => {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        resolve([results, fields]);
                    });
                });
            }; 
            
            const [results, fields] = await autoreasd(Verificare);
            const Mappa1 = results.map(results => `${(results.used)}`);
            const Mappa2 = results.map(results => `${(results.total_time)}`);
            var TempoAttesa = parseInt (Mappa1, 10);
            var TempoAttesa2 = parseInt (Mappa2, 10);
            function ConvertireTimp(UNIX_timestamp){
                var exilied_time = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
                var mesi = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
                exilied_time.setDate(exilied_time.getDate() + TempoAttesa2);
                var year = exilied_time.getFullYear();
                var month = mesi[exilied_time.getMonth()];
                var date = exilied_time.getDate();
                var hour = exilied_time.getHours();
                var min = exilied_time.getMinutes();
                var sec = exilied_time.getSeconds();
                var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ":"+  min;
                return time;
            } 
            message.delete()
            var convertireatimp =  ConvertireTimp(TempoAttesa2)
            var expirelicense = automex.send("**__Your License Expired On__**: \n" +  "" + convertireatimp + " \n If Not See Date Your Key Is Expired")
            } else { 
                automex.send("**You Dont Have A License Key**")
            }
        }
});```
````

Comment: Please be more specific than "It doesn't work." Provide details about what you expect to happen/see vs. what is happening, etc.

Comment: I attached two pictures, when I try to check the time of the license gives me undefined. 
Your License Expired On: 
NaN undefined NaN NaN:NaN

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.